# Multiply textbox value with a value stored on a cell on a google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

What I'm trying to do, is to take a number as input from a user through an HTML form and then multiply that number with a value stored on a google spreadsheet, say a value is stored in A2 of Sheet "sheet1" and then after the calculation display the result to the user in an html page preferably.

Let's say, the user enters 42, and the value stored in A2 of Sheet 1 is 3, I want the result

> (user input * A2 value)

or 42*3=126 to be displayed to the user in any format. I don't want the answer, in this case, 126 to be stored on the spreadsheet. i.e, i know it's possible to retrieve 126 from the spreadsheet, but I want the calculation to be done somewhere between the html page and the spreadsheet.

how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

From form, you can get input value by using its id like this in javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('YOUR ID').value;
```

(e.g. your ID can be like this: `<input type="text" id="YOUR ID"....>`)

now you can pass this variable's value to google appscript using:

```
google.script.run.YOURFUNCTION(a);
```

and then in your 'code.gs' file, write this function:

```
function YOURFUNCTION(somevalue)
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var result = (sheet.getRange('A2').getValue()) * somevalue;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the sidebar to display results. Or a messagebox.